# Replace a string stored in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm developing a program in python3 and need to iterate over a list of dictionaries and replace all occurances of a specific character '-' to '_'. Ideally, I only need to replace instances of '-' in dictionary keys, but I can manage otherwise

data is in the following format:

```
d=[
    {
    'title': [('Agente 007, Moonraker: Operazione spazio', 'it')], 
    'sub-title': [('Missione nel cosmo per...', 'it')], 
    },{
    'title': [('Agente 007, Vivi e lascia morire', 'it')], 
    'sub-title': [('Il primo James Bond con...', 'it')]
    }
  ]
```

I tried replacing it as you would a string with:

```
d.replace('-','_')
```

But that gave error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Then I figured I'd iterate over the list and dictionary items to try and replace:

```
 for i in range(len(dicts)):
     for x in dicts[i].items():
         dicts[i].items.replace('-','_')
```

which gave me

```
 AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

So now I'm trying

```
def t(dicts):
    for i in range(len(dicts)):
        for key in dicts[i].items():
            dicts[i].items()[key.replace('-','_')] = (dicts[i].items()).pop(key)
```

however, that gives error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Does anybody know how to do this? And if it's something I'm doing wrong, what would be the **correct** method of going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,

```
for i in range(len(dicts)):
 for x in dicts[i].items():
     dicts[i].items.replace('-','_')
```

you get the exception because you try to reach a method "replace" in the function "items" and not the **calling of the function**. it should be:

```
dicts[i].items().replace('-','_')
```

Secondly, for me that's the wrong approach.
Since you're using python, why not do it the pythonic way and just return a new list of new dicts that have new values?

The function provided below takes a list of dicts of lists of tuples (it's the structure you provided) and replaces every "to_change" to "change_to". I'm calling it using your demands to changing every '-' to '_'.

```
d=[
{
'title': [('Agente 007, Moonraker: Operazione spazio', 'it')], 
'sub-title': [('Missione nel cosmo per...', 'it')], 
},{
'title': [('Agente 007, Vivi e lascia morire', 'it')], 
'sub-title': [('Il primo James Bond con...', 'it')]
}
  ]  

def sub_string(dict_list, to_change, change_to):
    new_list = []
    for d_orig in dict_list:
        d_new = {}
        for key in d_orig.keys():
            new_key = key.replace(to_change, change_to)
            new_value = [[s.replace(to_change, change_to) for s in tup] for tup in d_orig[key]]
            d_new[new_key] = new_value

        new_list.append(d_new)
    return new_list

sub_string(d, '-', '_')
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: Well, I'm a bit torn.
I want to accept the answer because it is the pythonic way, but with my large dataset it's causing a buffer overflow and segfault

Comment: I understand your conflict, but think about it this way:
say your dataset is a million times the size of the dict you supplied (which is probably a strech), it will take around **11 seconds** to do this replacing of the data. Of course there are optimizations to be done, but for a one time click and forget function it isn't that bad.